# How to remove searchview from some fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

Hello i have two fragments named : OneFragment and ThreeFragment.

OneFragment is loaded with ViewPager in Fragment called : AllNewsFragment.

ThreeFragment is loaded with ViewPager in Fragment called : SoccerFragment.

Like : AllNewsFragment-> OneFragment

SoccerFragment-> ThreeFragment

i have added a searchview to OneFragment using this code :

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(((navigation) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(
                new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return true;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(View v) {

                                          }
                                      }
        );

    }
```

It s working prefectly but the problem that when switching to ThreeFragment the searchview is still displayed in ThreeFragment.

I have tried to implement the same code onCreateOptionsMenu in ThreeFragment and added searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE); but it's not working..

I want to display the searchview only in OneFragment and remove it from ThreeFragment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform searching in one Fragment then do search using Edittext and put Your EditText in One Fragment(AllNewsFragment) XML.
Like if your EditText named as(searchbox) then you can search like this:

```
   searchbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //after the change calling the method and passing the search input
           adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        }
    });
```